# Using webpack resolveLoader alias or how to shorten require path

Tags: webpack

I have this:

```js
let avatar = require ('../../../public/assets/img/avatar.jpg');
```

I want to be able to use something like this:

```js
let avatar = require('alias!./img/avatar.jpg');
```

What I try to do is set an alias in webpack config like this:

```js
resolveLoader: {
    alias: {
        'alias': path.join(__dirname, '../public/assets/'),
    }
},
```

Path does resolve to a correct directory and the file is there. The original long require works correctly. But using the alias I get an

*Error: Cannot resolve 'file' or 'directory' ./img/avatar.jpg*

Am I missing something in alias config or maybe I'm not using the correct tool to achieve this altogether ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`resolveLoader`](https://webpack.js.org/configuration/resolve/#resolveloader) is used to resolve loaders, but the path you have given is not a loader.

In webpack, I usually do something like this in `resolve.alias`.

```js
resolve: {
  alias: {
    '@assets': '@/public/assets',
  },
}
```

The above creates an alias for `src/public/assets`, using `@assets`.

Now you can do:

```js
let avatar = require ('@assets/img/avatar.jpg');
```

This will allow webpack to resolve it to the correct path.

Answer (score 0):

One approach would be to set the `modulesDirectories` option, to define a new folder you'd like webpack to resolve paths against.

https://webpack.github.io/docs/configuration.html#resolve-modulesdirectories

Without seeing your `webpack.config.js`.  I also suspect, you may want to be setting these options to `resolve` not `resolveLoader`

```
resolve: {
    modulesDirectories: [
        'path/to/assets'
    ]
},
```

and then...

```
let avatar = require('./img/avatar.jpg');
// should look at 'path/to/assets/img/avatar.jpg'
```