# Shorten ES2015 import paths

Tags: javascript, webpack, ecmascript-6, babeljs

I am working on a large ES2015 project that has a lot of import statements referring to a library in a deep directory structure. Currently, imports take the form of

```
import Status from '../../../Scripts/core/components/Status';
//import ...
```

Are there any workarounds to shorten the length of import paths other than changing the location of the source files?

edit: I am using babel-loader with webpack to compile the modules.

Comment: Since ES2015 modules aren't actually implemented in any JavaScript engines, the answer to your question will depend heavily on what technology you are using to fake ES2015 modules. You should include that in your question. E.g., are these "Babel modules", or "TypeScript modules", or...?

Comment: The module loader is not part of ECMAScript. You'd have to read the documentation of your environment / tool that you are using to load modules if they provide an option for that. So, this has nothing to do with ES6, but with the environment / tool you are using.

Comment: Good point, I edited the post to add that I am using webpack + babel.

Comment: webpack gives you the ability to define *aliases*: https://webpack.github.io/docs/configuration.html#resolve-alias .

Comment: If it truly is a library, why not have it be in `node_modules`?

Comment: Related: [Using webpack resolveLoader alias or how to shorten require path](http://stackoverflow.com/q/35796898/218196)

Comment: It's an in-house library that is in development and won't be published through npm.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can also use [`resolve.alias`](https://webpack.github.io/docs/configuration.html#resolve-alias) to handle roots that might move around:

```
resolve: {
  alias: {
    importName: 'actual/path/here',
    '__another_alias__': 'another/path'
  }
}
```

Which you could then use as:

```
import someImport from 'importName';
import anotherImport from '__another_alias__/sub/path';
```

Answer (score 1):

One common pattern is to have a single file that imports all the components of a similar context and then exports them all. Then you can `import` from this single file at a much higher level in the tree. For example, **Angular2** does [this](https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/master/modules/angular2/core.ts).

```
/**
 * @module
 * @description
 * Starting point to import all public core APIs.
 */
export * from './src/core/metadata';
export * from './src/core/util';
export * from './src/core/prod_mode';
export * from './src/core/di';
export * from './src/facade/facade';
export {enableProdMode} from 'angular2/src/facade/lang';
export {
  createPlatform,
  assertPlatform,
  disposePlatform,
  getPlatform,
  coreBootstrap,
  coreLoadAndBootstrap,
  createNgZone,
  PlatformRef,
  ApplicationRef
} from './src/core/application_ref';
export {
  APP_ID,
  APP_INITIALIZER,
  PACKAGE_ROOT_URL,
  PLATFORM_INITIALIZER
} from './src/core/application_tokens';
export * from './src/core/zone';
export * from './src/core/render';
export * from './src/core/linker';
export {DebugElement, DebugNode, asNativeElements} from './src/core/debug/debug_node';
export * from './src/core/testability/testability';
export * from './src/core/change_detection';
export * from './src/core/platform_directives_and_pipes';
export * from './src/core/platform_common_providers';
export * from './src/core/application_common_providers';
export * from './src/core/reflection/reflection';
```

As you can see, rather than having to `import {Foo} from './src/core/platform_common_providers'` for example you simply do `import {Foo} from "angular2/core"`

Comment: Ahhhhh. I was presuming Angular's source tree had basically 5 classes all in one TypeScript file. I had started to design my modules with several small classes in one source file, supposedly imitating them. This makes more sense.

Comment: This is very helpful, I am going to look into this and webpack aliases and see which one makes more sense to use for my use-case.

Answer (score 0):

Another possibility is Babel's `resolveModuleSource` option, but note that it can only be configured programatically, not via `.babelrc`, and is only going to apply to module syntax compiled by Babel. So for example if you need to reference the lib from code that's not module syntax compiled by Babel, that might favor doing it via the bundler (Webpack) or by putting the lib in `node_modules` (it doesn't matter that you're not publishing it to npm) as others have suggested in the comments.

Note that if you do it via the bundler, that'll only work in the bundled output, not for running the code in Node directly / using Babel's require hook. So consider for example how you'll test this code. Are you going to bundle the tests? It's possible you may want to use several of these options in combination or in different contexts.